# how to check that some input is of type sympy function?

Tags: python, sympy

I just started learning basic parsing in sympy, and having little trouble with this.

I want to make a `proc()`, which the caller will pass it a symbolic function, and the argument to the function, each as separate argument. i.e. instead of calling the proc as `proc( y(x) )`, I wanted to call it as `proc(y,x)`, which I thought will be easier for me to check its arguments are what should be.

Next, inside the proc, wanted to first verify that the first argument type is indeed a sympy function and the second argument is a sympy symbol before doing any processing.

What is the correct way to check that the argument is a sympy function and nothing else? This is what I tried. Created one file:

```
================
def process(y,x):
    if not isinstance(x, sympy.Symbol):
        raise Exception(x + " should be a sympy symbol")

    if not isinstance(y,sympy.UndefinedFunction): #this does not work
        raise Exception(y + " should be a sympy function")


import sympy
x   = sympy.symbols('x')
y   = sympy.Function('y')
process(y,x)
======================
```

But there is no `sympy.UndefinedFunction`. When I type

```
type(y)
Out[18]: sympy.core.function.UndefinedFunction
```

But

```
 isinstance(y,sympy.core.function.UndefinedFunction)
```

does not work either.  May be there is a better way to do all the above. Basically I wanted to make sure the input to the proc is what it should be.

Using 3.7 (conda)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sympy.UndefinedFunction` with `sympy.function.UndefinedFunction`.

Also, `x` and `y` in `Exception` function should be of type string, otherwise you will get `unsupported operand type(s) for +:` error in both cases.

New code:

```
def process(y,x):
    if not isinstance(x, sympy.symbol.Symbol):
        raise Exception(str(x) + " should be a sympy symbol")

    if not isinstance(y,sympy.function.UndefinedFunction):
        raise Exception(str(y) + " should be a sympy function")

import sympy
x   = sympy.symbols('x')
y   = sympy.Function('y')
process(y,x)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked., But could you explain how you found it should be sympy.function.UndefinedFunction and not anything else? This is what I think I find confusing in sympy. I do not know the correct full name for such things. Since type(y) gives something else than what you used. For example, why did the name for `Symbol` work but not for `Function` as I used them?

Comment: Try to use `isinstance(y,sympy.core.function.UndefinedFunction)`.  You will get error that `AttributeError: module sympy.core.core has no attribute function`. See here core module has been applied twice. It means it's applying `core` on its own.