# How to check if sympy recognizes a function when it's parsed by sympify()?

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following example where an arbitrary mathematical expression is given.

```py
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> expr = sp.sympify("sin(x) + foo(y)")
```

Above, `sin` is the sine function which sympy recognizes (and can use, evaluate, invert during solving, etc), but `foo` is a function unknown to sympy:

```py
>>> expr.subs('x', sp.pi/2)
foo(y) + 1

>>> expr.subs('y', sp.pi/2)
foo(pi/2) + sin(x)

>>> eq = sp.Eq(sp.sympify('z'), expr)

>>> sp.solve(eq, 'x')
[pi - asin(z - foo(y)), asin(z - foo(y))]

>>> sp.solve(eq, 'z')
[foo(y) + sin(x)]

>>> sp.solve(eq, 'y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
NotImplementedError: 
No algorithms are implemented to solve equation z - foo(y) - sin(x)
```

Is there any way by which to differentiate between these two "categories" of functions (i.e. sympy-defined and not)?  So that one can extract all instances of either with something like e.g.

```py
>>> [func for func in eq.atoms(sp.Function) if is_sympy_defined(func)]
[sin(x)]

>>> [func for func in eq.atoms(sp.Function) if not is_sympy_defined(func)]
[foo(y)]
```

I've compared the attributes of both functions ( `sympify('sin(x)')` and `sympify('foo(x)')` ), but there doesn't seem to be any indication on either function that one is sympy-defined and the other not.

Googling my title brings up [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57107924/how-to-check-that-some-input-is-of-type-sympy-function), but it seems not to do exactly what I want (despite the name sounding appropriate):

```py
>>> from sympy.core.function import UndefinedFunction

>>> sin = sp.sympify("sin(x)")
>>> isinstance(sin, UndefinedFunction)
>>> False  # expected

>>> foo = sp.sympify("foo(x)")
>>> isinstance(foo, UndefinedFunction)
>>> False  # unexpected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined functions when called are instance of `AppliedUndef`:

```
In [13]: from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef

In [14]: e = sympify("sin(x) + foo(y)")

In [15]: e.atoms(Function) # All functions
Out[15]: {foo(y), sin(x)}

In [16]: e.atoms(AppliedUndef) # Undefined functions
Out[16]: {foo(y)}

In [17]: e.atoms(Function) - e.atoms(AppliedUndef) # Defined functions
Out[17]: {sin(x)}
```

Comment: This is an excellently clear and concise way of doing it.  The last statement is a little verbose but can be wrapped in a utility function if necessary.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a dedicated function in the API to achieve that, but you could simply check if your function is part of [sympy.functions](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/functions/__init__.py):

```
import sympy as sp

sin_f = sp.sympify("sin(x + y)")
print(str(sin_f.func) in sp.functions.__all__) #True

foo = sp.sympify("foo(x)")
print(str(foo.func) in sp.functions.__all__) #False
```

(I renamed `sin` to `sin_f` to make clear that `func` refers to the underlying function)